# push and pop of fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments A and B in activity.If a button is pressed in fragment A then it replaces the  fragment B.Then the action is completed in fragment B it immediately switch back to fragment A to perform the updated action and it should return to fragment B.How to achieve this.I have searched a lot.But nothing is related to this.

Please guide me to complete this.

Answer (score 0):

Every communication between fragments should be performed via the parent activity.
From each fragment, tell the parent activity to call the other fragment. And, the other fragment should also tell the activity upon completion of task.